# $(ab)^2=a^2b^2$ doesn't hold for semigroup.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups, semigroups

I am trying to prove that
$(ab)^2=a^2b^2$ doesn't hold for a semigroup $S$. It is easy to prove(using inverse property) that the above condition holds for an abelian group. However, for semigroup, it doesn't hold. Is it because that the inverse element doesn't exist in $S$? How to prove formally?

**Edit:** I found the above question in an undergraduate book. I think that it should have been stated as

> Give a counter example to show that $(ab)^2=a^2b^2$ doesn't necessarily hold in a semigroup.

The answer is as stated by Arthur and Thomas  in the comments.

Comment: what is a semi-group?

Comment: @EveryonesaysFU It's a non-empty set with a closed, associative binary operation. There is no assumption of an identity element, and thus obviously no assumption of inverses.

Comment: it doesn't even hold for a group in general (if it's not abelian, as you say). do you mean that you want a counter example in the case of an abelian semi group?

Comment: All you have to do is find one semigroup for which it is not true.

Comment: Sometimes it holds and sometimes it doesn't,

Comment: @EveryonesaysFU A non empty set with a binary operation, which is associative.

Comment: You say it doesn't hold for semigroups, but $(\Bbb Z, +)$ is a semigroup. and it holds there. So what exactly is it that you're asking about?

Comment: is it taught in university?

Comment: @EveryonesaysFU I think most people first learn about semigroups well after they have become familiar with groups and are more or less comfortable with the basics of abstract algebra. Wich yes, puts this squarely into what I would consider "university level" math. Whether it's actually _taught_ there, as in there are classes and exams on the topic, that depends on the university.

Comment: As an example, take any abelian group. As a counterexample, take any nonabelian group. So (like Arthur already asked) what is your question?

Comment: @Albert yes, a counter example of an abelian semigroup would be fine for this question.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Yes, in this case, the set of natural numbers with respect to usual addition is a counter example.

Comment: @Arthur I copied the question from a book, it should have been said "prove that $(ab)^2=a^2b^2$ doesn't hold in general for a semigroup". By the ways, in your example $(\Bbb Z, +)$ , it doesn't hold if "+" means usual addition.

Comment: @EveryonesaysFU found in undergraduate level book

Comment: @gete "Prove it doesn't hold in general for a semigroup" is a very different thing from "show it doesn't hold for semigroup $S$". To prove a property doesn't hold in general, a single counterexample is usually the quickest way to go. And yes, the property "$(ab)^2 = a^2b^2$" does hold in the semigroup $\Bbb Z$ with standard addition (and it also holds in the semigroup $\Bbb Z$ with standard multiplication). You just have to twist your mind into writing addition miltiplicatively.

Comment: @gete Well, the natural numbers under addition is an example where $(ab)^2=a^2b^2.$ But to prove that this equality is not true in some semigroups, you need to find one example of a semigroup where there is at least one pair, $a,b,$ with $(ab)^2=a^2b^2.$ Any non-abelian group will do, because in a group, $(ab)^2=a^2b^2$ is equivalent to $ba=ab.$

Comment: So I was treating the statement as "It is not true that, for all semigroups $S,$ and $a,b \in S,$ we have $(ab)^2=a^2b^2.$" To find a proof, you only need one semigroup $S,$ and one pair $a,b\in S$ with $(ab)^2\neq a^2b^2.$

Answer (score 2):

In fact, it doesn't even have to be true in a group. If we take $S_3$ as our group and take $a$ as (12) and $b$ as (123), then this doesn't hold.

Answer (score 2):

> I am trying to prove that $(ab)^2=a^2b^2$ doesn't hold for a semigroup $S$.

You mean "it doesn't have to hold".

> It is easy to prove(using inverse property) that the above condition
> holds for an abelian group.

Indeed. Moreover you don't have to look outside of groups for a counterexample. In fact:

> **Lemma.** A group $G$ is abelian if and only if for any $a,b\in G$ we have $(ab)^2=a^2b^2$.

*Proof.* "$\Rightarrow$" obvious.

"$\Leftarrow$" $(ab)^2=a^2b^2$ can be written equivalently as

$$abab=aabb$$

Now just multiply by $a^{-1}$ from the left and $b^{-1}$ from the right (both exist because we are dealing with a group) to obtain $ba=ab$. $\Box$

---

So all you have to do is to pick your favourite non-abelian group, since every group is a semigroup. For example the symmetric group $S_n$ for $n\geq 3$ does the job.

Answer (score 1):

As other people have mentioned, all you need is one example.

You could take $S$ to be the free semigroup of words with characters $a$ and $b$ with the operation of concatenation of words.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_monoid